# how can i add gesture recognizer to segment view in ios objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol, xcode8

I want to use gestures for segment view. is it possible?
I am using segment view with to change the color of a view and I want to use swipe gesture.

```
Override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

var swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "respondToSwipeGesture:")
swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)
```

is it a right way to use gestures.

Comment: Think that the segment View has two controllers, in which one are you declaring this?

Comment: Can you give more details about your set up?

Comment: plz add some more information about your question

Comment: i'm having 2 or more views in one view controller and and i want to scroll them automatically and also using swipe gestures. what is the way of coding for the requirement. i want to use segmented control...